# No puedo utilizar conexión en Netbeans con java

Tags: java, base-de-datos, jdbc

he estado tratando de seguir un modelo de proyecto de mi profesor, lo que requiere que cree una clase de conexión y la use en un método en un servicio web. He replicado el código del ejemplo, pero sigo recibiendo el error "no se puede obtener el símbolo". Tengo la sensación de que falta algún import, pero no estoy seguro.

Aquí está mi código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has importado la interfaz Connection, ahora importa PreparedStatement y ResultSet. Todo esta en el paquete java.sql. También mira "stmt = setInt..." que debería ser stmt.setInt(1, rut) para establecer el parámetro a la consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude echar a andar mi código c: